# terraform validate recursively

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terraform

I am trying to run terraform validate(v1.16) in automation.
Is there a way to run terraform validation recursively in all directories, and subdirectories in a given path.

and if I would want to run `terraform validation` in such case do I need to initialize  even the subdirectories ?
ex-:

```
 |-d1-infra
 | |-outputs.tf
 | |-main.tf
 | |-tfmodules
 | | |-new_host1
 | | | |-outputs.tf
 | | | |-variables.tf
 | | | |-ay.tf
 | | | |-cn.tf
 | | |-new_host2
 | | | |-outputs.tf
 | | | |-variables.tf
 | | | |-y.tf
 | | | |-n.tf
 | |-pol.tf
 | |-variables.tf
 | |-data.tf
 | |-backend.tf
 | |-host1.tf
```

How can I validate this in a shell script
currently I am doing

```
tf_dirs_to_validate=(d1-infra d2-infra d3-infra)
for d in "${tf_dirs_to_validate[@]}" ; do
if [ "`cd ./$$d && terraform init -input=false -backend=false > /dev/null && terraform validate -json`" ]; then
echo "===>Terraform format check passed successfully in <---- $$d -->"
else
    echo "validation failed in <---- $$d -->" && exit 1
fi
done;
```

but this seems to validate only on the top level dir i.e, `d1-infra` `d2-infra` `d3-infra` but doesn't validates the modules

Comment: Yes, init has to take place in all directories for validate to work.

Comment: This is more of a bash thingy rather terraform. You can find all child directories with *.tf extension, fetch the directory names & the repeat the `terraform init` followed by `terraform validate`

Linux command to find unique child directories containing .tf files ..

`find /dir -type f -name '*.tf' -printf '%h\n' | uniq`

Comment: `terraform validate` expects to be applied to a root module (one intended for `terraform apply`) rather than a shared module (one to be used in a `module` block). However, it will validate the entire configuration, including all of the called modules. You mentioned that isn't happening for you; it would help if you could update your question with more information about what led you to that conclusion.

Comment: @MartinAtkins No it doesn't as in this case under tf-modules > host1 > variables.tf If I remove a block of variable which is in use by the module , terraform validate doesn't show any error for that not even a warning

Comment: I just tried referring to `var.missing` in a child module and then validating the top-level module that was calling it. Terraform reported "Reference to undeclared input variable", as I expected. Something unusual seems to be happening for you, but it's impossible to guess what's going on without more information.

Answer (score 1):

@Jenifer, I guess you can take help of terragrunt in this case. Terragrunt is a thin wrapper for Terraform, so when you run any terragrunt command (like plan,validate, apply etc) Terragrunt executes subsequent terraform command.

In your case, you can use below command

```
terragrunt run-all validate
```

Reference : https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/cli-options/#validate-all-deprecated-use-run-all

The same can be incorporated in your bash script.

Comment: Hedge not looking for wrapper solutions